# Keeping iframe/image ratio when resizing on height

Tags: javascript, iframe, aspect-ratio, window-resize, resize-image

I managed to keep the iframe's ratio for when the user resizes the window on width, but I have trouble adding the logic for when the user resizes the window on height due to conflicting logic, since the resize on width already alters the height of the iframe.

This is the function that gets called when resizing:

```
function calculateAspectRatioFit(width, height, ratio) {
  if(height) {
    let width = ((length)/(Math.sqrt((1)/(Math.pow(ratio, 2)+1))));
    return Math.round(width);
  } else if(width) {
    let height = ((width)/(Math.sqrt((Math.pow(ratio, 2)+1))));
    return Math.round(height);
  }
}
```

But I believe that the problem lies in the trigger:

```
const resizeHandler = (e) => {
   console.log("inside ", parseInt(iframeHeight), iframeElement.offsetHeight);

   if(parseInt(iframeWidth) > iframeElement.offsetWidth) {
      // overwrite inline styling
      iframeElement.style.cssText = 'height: ' + calculateAspectRatioFit(iframeElement.offsetWidth, null, iframeRatio) + 'px!important';
   } else if (parseInt(iframeHeight) > window.innerHeight) {
      iframeElement.style.cssText = 'width: ' + calculateAspectRatioFit(null, iframeElement.offsetHeight, iframeRatio) + 'px!important';
   }
}
```

Got any solutions for this? (pen below)

https://codepen.io/Dragosb/pen/WNoeXRa?editors=0011

Answer (score 0):

Solved, as per the codepen (link is the same as the one in the original post):

Added a container for the iframe (if you are using a modal, that can be the container):

```
const resizeHandler = (e) => {
  // get container measures
  let computedContainerStyling = getComputedStyle(iframeContainer);
  let containerWidth = parseInt(computedContainerStyling.width);
  let containerHeight = parseInt(computedContainerStyling.height);

  if ( (containerWidth / iframeRatio) > containerHeight){
    iframeHeight = containerHeight;
    iframeWidth = containerHeight * iframeRatio;    
  } else {
    iframeWidth = containerWidth;
    iframeHeight = containerWidth / iframeRatio;
  }
  iframeElement.style.width = Math.floor(iframeWidth) + 'px';
  iframeElement.style.height = Math.floor(iframeHeight) + 'px';
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeHandler, false);
```

https://codepen.io/Dragosb/pen/WNoeXRa?editors=0011